# Configure SQL server access depending on port

Tags: sql-server, security

Can SQL server listen on more than one port for connections?  If so, can one of the ports be setup to only allow read access?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of playing with ports why don’t you try creating a login and providing only read access to it, I thing it’s much better eBay easiest way to do.

Comment: Yaa , in my opinion too that is a better solution. Since SQL ACL's are based on user login and not on connection sources / origins.